# How can I detect carried objects from depth/skeleton data

Tags: python, object-detection, depth

I'm using the azure kinect camera to record RGB-D/depth/skeleton data of human factory workers. I want to detect if the worker is lifting/carrying a object. However, I have trouble with finding a method to do this.